# Momentjs: Date to first month

Tags: momentjs

I'm getting this output:

```
>> moment('18/07/2019@14:15:56.513+0000', 'dd/MM/yyyy@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
>> "01/07/2019"
```

I need to get `18/07/2019` instead of `01/07/2019`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `moment('18/07/2019@14:15:56.513+0000', 'dd/MM/yyyy@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ').format('DD/MM/YYYY');` to:

`moment('18/07/2019@14:15:56.513+0000', 'DD/MM/yyyy@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ').format('DD/MM/YYYY');`  should do the trick. Note that the first `dd` was changed to `DD`.

According to moment.js docs (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) , `DD` is the mask for current day of month.

Answer (score 0):

Moment tokens are case sensitive, so you have to use `'DD/MM/YYYY[@]HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'` instead of `'dd/MM/yyyy@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'`. Lowercase `dd` stands for week day name (locale aware), while there is no lowercase `yyyy`, use uppercase `YYYY` for years.

See [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) docs.

You can use square brackets `[]` to escape character.

Here a live sample:

```js
console.log( moment('18/07/2019@14:15:56.513+0000', 'DD/MM/YYYY[@]HH:mm:ss.SSSZ').format('DD/MM/YYYY') );
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```